# Mockito BDD - mocking RestRemplate exchange() method

Tags: spring, mockito, bdd, resttemplate

I'm trying to mock a RestTemplate exchange() call with the following code:

**Test method**

```
given(restTemplate.exchange(any(UriComponents.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), any(StatusResponse.class)))
            .willReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY));
```

The code does not compile because:

1. it complains that `cannot resolve method willReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY))`
2. it complains that `cannot resolve method exchange(T, T, T, T)`

How should I change the signature to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st argument of `exchange` (url) should be `eq("url")` or `anyString()` (assumning that "url" is the value you're using in your test).

The 4th argument (response class) should be `eq(StatusResponse.class)` or `any(Class.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) at the exchange methods. I don't see any method which uses `UriComponents` in arguments.

As the first argument of exchange method you need to use `String` , `URI` or `RequestEntity`

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I was actually using `builder.toUri()` that returns a `String`. I wrongly used the type of the `builder` variable.